# HTML icon didn't load correctly when deploying Django to Google Cloud

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, django-staticfiles, django-settings

I have some trouble when deploying Django to Google Cloud.

Currently, I'm using Django2.2.
The HTML icon didn't load correctly when I open it from my laptop.
But when open it using my mobile browser, it will show the icon perfectly.
Already try to clear cache and cookies but still doesn't work, not sure why.

The images and CSS in `static/` directory can be loaded, but only the HTML icon that can't be load correctly.

I've followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment) itself.

And I think it's kinda funny cause I've tried to deploy using `DEBUG = True` and change the `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` but everything works perfectly.

But, as it says from [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#debug), that we need to change the `DEBUG` to `False` when in productions.

Here are my `settings.py` looks like:

```py
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
...


MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static/')
STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/djangodbs/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'

# STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/'
]
```

Here are some of the screenshot:

[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/945ok.png)

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saZQQ.jpg)

Comment: _...and we need to configure our webserver to serve static and media files because Django in Debug=False will no longer do this_

Comment: @IvanStarostin so what you suggest? can you please send me documentation to configure it?

Comment: here is a hint for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981805/nginx-configuration-with-static-files-under-django#comment98613981_55981805