# Nginx Configuration with Static Files under Django

Tags: django, nginx, django-staticfiles, nginx-config

I am setting an Nginx configuration with my Django project.
In order to provide some static file without `/static/` showing on the URL,
I add some rewrite rules in Nginx configuration.

Here is part of my Nginx configuration:

```
    location /static/ {
        location ~* \.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|js)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
        }
        alias /path/to/myproject/static/;
    }

    location ~ ^/favicon.ico$ {
        rewrite ^/favicon.ico$ /static/favicon.ico;
    }

    location /foo/ {
        rewrite ^/foo/(.*)$ /static/abc/$1;
    }

    location /bar/ {
        rewrite ^/bar/(.*)$ /static/bar/$1;
    }

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass myproject;
        include django_fastcgi_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
```

When I access https://myproject.com/foo, it will show 404 page of Django. I think it is because there is no matching location in Nginx (should end up with slash `/`) and no matching URL in Django's `urls.py`.

When I access https://myproject.com/foo/, it will show `index.html` under `myproject/static/foo/` folder, or it will be 403 Forbidden if there is no `index.html`.

But I found that...

When I access https://myproject.com/foo/abc, it will 301 Moved Permanently to https://myproject.com/static/foo/abc/

When I access https://myproject.com/foo/abc/, it will directly show https://myproject.com/foo/abc/, which is the `index.html` file under `myproject/static/abc/`

Why these two URLs work differently?

Is there any modification I should do?

Comment: Please show your `settings.py` file?

Comment: Are you asking why your `location /` block does not automatically append a `/` but your other `location` blocks do?

Comment: This config is too obfuscated and has lost significant details or something is not true here. There is no line enabling indexing (listing files) in this config and 403 is correct (example 2), which means that _directly showing files under some folder_ (example 4) is not really possible.

Comment: I set APPEND_SLASH=True in my settings.py. But I think I am trying to serve these static files without Django. That why I add these rules in Nginx configuration.

Comment: @RichardSmith I think both https://myproject.com/foo/abc and https://myproject.com/foo/abc/ should match the rule location /foo/. So my question is why these two URLs work differently.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Sorry for making confusion. There is a general configuration with index index.html.

Comment: Just trying to understand your question. Are you trying to prevent an external redirection from `/foo` to `/static/abc/`, preferring it to redirect from `/foo` to `/foo/` instead?

Comment: @RichardSmith It is better to say that why myproject.com/foo/abc does 301 redirect but myproject.com/foo/abc/ doesn't.

Comment: That's just how `index` works. If `/foo/abc` points to a directory, the default behaviour is to append a `/` using an external redirect. Then, if `/foo/abc/` points to a directory, the default behaviour is to look for a file matching one of the values of the `index` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `APPEND_SLASH=False` setting in the `settings.py` of django project. For more information see this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: I set APPEND_SLASH=True in my settings.py. But I think I am trying to serve these static files without Django. That why I add these rules in Nginx configuration.